# Sending String from shared preferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I would like to know how(if possible) to send my String from my Shared preferences, to an array of Strings I have so that my other class will be able to read it so the images can be displayed.

I know that getting "imgUrl" will give me the correct image URL corresponding to the image that is being viewed.

I'm really stuck on how I would be able to achieve this, any help would be great..

Class:

```
    case R.id.FavouriteWallpaper:


        SharedPreferences prefs;
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("imgUrl", mImageUrl);
        editor.commit();

        break;

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



  //Somehow get "imgUrl" from Sharedprefs to be displayed in this format:

public static final String[] ImageFavs = new String[] {

           "www.URLTOBEDISPLAYEDHERE.jpg"

};
```

Comment: Please look at [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) for how to store and retrive data in SharedPreferences in Android. Also please ask your question to [google](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=shared+preference+in+android&oq=shared&aqs=chrome.3.69i57j69i60j0l4.5851j0j8&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) before asking here.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this.?

```
String uri=prefs.getString("imgUrl", "default uri");
```